# why is the state of useState shared even though I created individual components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently working with React components, and I'm experiencing an issue with shared state in the `Area component`. The component has a `count state`, and the problem arises when multiple instances of the component are created.

```
function Area({ title }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>current area : {title}</h2>
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
          +1
        </button>
        <div>count : {count}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const menuInfos = [
  { title: "aaaaaa", children: <Area title="aaaaaa" /> },
  { title: "bbbbbb", children: <Area title="bbbbbb" /> },
  { title: "cccccc", children: <Area title="cccccc" /> },
  { title: "dddddd", children: <Area title="dddddd" /> },
  { title: "eeeeee", children: <Area title="eeeeee" /> }
];
```

In the current code, the `Area component` is used within the `Menu component`, and an instance is created for each menu item. However, when `Area component` is used across multiple menu items, the count variable is shared, leading to unexpected behavior.

[image: share state working]

Code sandbox working link : https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-wind-59v5j9?file=/src/_app.js

I would like to understand reasons about this work and to find a solution to manage the count state eparately for each menu item. I would appreciate any advice on how to modify the code to achieve this.

I have utilized the `useEffect hook` within the `Area component` to log the unmount phase using `console.log, and the unmount process appears to be functioning correctly.

Additionally, I compared the children  components from the `menuInfos array`, which are passed as `props` to the `Menu component`, using Object.is, and they are recognized as distinct objects.

However, despite these observations, I am struggling to fully comprehend the issue at hand. It seems that I might have overlooked something crucial in my understanding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

React uses a property called `key` during rendering so it does not update things that do not need updating. If a parent is rendered that has a child for which `key` is the same as before, then it will do an optimized, reduced kind of rendering which apparently means that updates for `{count}` are not being done. It's a different component, but React does not know it.

Adding `key` properties will make your code work:

```
const menuInfos = [
  { title: "aaaaaa", children: <Area key="a" title="aaaaaa" /> },
  { title: "bbbbbb", children: <Area key="b" title="bbbbbb" /> },
  { title: "cccccc", children: <Area key="c" title="cccccc" /> },
  { title: "dddddd", children: <Area key="d" title="dddddd" /> },
  { title: "eeeeee", children: <Area key="e" title="eeeeee" /> }
];
```

**Update:** the code "works" but maybe not as you want... Because you only render one component at a time, the others seem to get unloaded and lose their state. The next time a component is shown again, its state is created again and starts at 0 again.

Comment: I knew I needed a key when rendering multiple components using Array.map. However, since this code uses Array.find, it actually only passes one component as a child. So I thought I wouldn't need a key, but it turns out I'm not! 

I am also learning new things. Thank you so much for letting me know!!!

Comment: React doesn't use keys during rendering (unless you provide keys, which author didn't). React uses position and type of element to determine if it should be remounted or not, and state is external to the component. Adding keys in this array is not a correct approach to rendering array of items. So this answer neither explains why it happens nor provides a real solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting your children components in an array you should use the array to store data that will populate your components. With a little CSS trick you can also keep your data even if you cicle between components:

```
import { useState } from "react";

// no need to set your children components here
const menuInfos = [
  { title: "aaaaaa" },
  { title: "bbbbbb" },
  { title: "cccccc" },
  { title: "dddddd" },
  { title: "eeeeee" }
];

function Area({ title }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>current area : {title}</h2>
      <div>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => setCount((current) => current + 1)}
        >
          +1
        </button>
        <div>count : {count}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Menu({ menuInfos }) {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(menuInfos[0].title);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          {menuInfos.map((info) => (
            <button
              key={info.title}
              style={{
                background: info.title === current ? "red" : ""
              }}
              onClick={() => setCurrent(info.title)}
            >
              {info.title}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>

      {/** render here your components */}
      {menuInfos.map((info, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          {/** here's the trick to keep your data between changes of menus */}
          style={{
            display: info.title === current ? "block" : "none"
          }}
        >
          <Area title={info.title} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Menu menuInfos={menuInfos} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-golick-m7vmyn?file=/src/_app.js:0-1385) is a working codesandbox example

Comment: When actually implementing a tab menu, it seems that using a global state store or the suggested method would be appropriate. In fact, when looking at other implementations of tab menus, they were similar to the suggested approach. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I will be fully honest with you: I can not completely explain, why your solution is not working. My best guess is, that your "children" are not really separate instances of `Area`, but instead the same instance with just different titles.

I rewrote your element mapping, so that it is working as intended. Please try it:

```
export default function Menu({ menuInfos }) {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(menuInfos[0].title);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          {menuInfos.map((info) => (
            <button
              style={{ background: info.title === current ? "red" : "" }}
              onClick={() => setCurrent(info.title)}
            >
              {info.title}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      {menuInfos.map(
        (info, index) =>
          info.title === current && (
            <div key={index}>
              <Area title={info.title} />
            </div>
          )
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see I duplicated the mapping of your menuInfos to create truly separate instances of `Area` with a conditional statement to only show the correct `Area`. The count-States are now separated from each other.

Comment: This sollution works fine but if he wants to keep changes between menus this will not work as react will unmount any unselected component

Comment: Yes you are right. To achieve this, the menuInfos-object could be used to store the count-values. The setter-function can be passed down to the Area-Component.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to ensure all child elements have a different position.

This change will make your code work:

```
<div>
   {menuInfos.map((info) => info.title === current && info.children)}
</div>
```

Why? Because an array is returned, e.g. `[false, false, <Area />]` so the visible Area element is in third position. React uses type and position to determine which element uses which state.

But your Area elements will get unmounted when you switch between them, resetting their state every time.

You could counter that by having them all in the DOM and hiding them visually:

```
<div>
  {menuInfos.map((info) => (
     <div style={info.title === current ? {} : { display: "none" }}>
        {info.children}
     </div>
   ))}
</div>
```